# Google finance: get YTD high

Tags: google-sheets, finance, stock, google-finance

I am trying to get the YTD **high** of a ticker using

```
=max(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL";"high";"01/01/2020"; today();"DAILY")))
```

but it does not work.

Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out a way by doing:

```
=max(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL";"high";"01/01/2021"; today()); ; 2))
```